# Как правильно инициализировать базу данных?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Здравствуйте. Приложение на платформе ASP.NET MVC, ORM Entity Framework, Code-First.

Файл Global.asax.cs:

```
public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new CustomerRegistrationDbInitializer());
        CustomerRegistrationContext dbContext = new CustomerRegistrationContext();
        dbContext.Database.Initialize(true);

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
}
```

Объектная модель базы данных:

```
public class Customer
{
    [Key] public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(100)] public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(100)] public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required, ForeignKey("City")] public int CityId { get; set; }
    [Required] public City City { get; set; }
}

public class City
{
    [Key] public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required] public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required, ForeignKey("Region")] public int RegionId { get; set; }
    [Required] public Region Region { get; set; }

    [Required, ForeignKey("Country")] public int CountryId { get; set; }
    [Required] public Country Country { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}

public class Region
{
    [Key] public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required] public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required, ForeignKey("Country")] public int CountryId { get; set; }
    [Required] public Country Country { get; set; }

    public virtual List<City> Cities { get; set; }
}

public class Country
{
    [Key] public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required] public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Region> Regions { get; set; }
    public virtual List<City> Cities { get; set; }
}
```

Классы контекста и инициализатора базы данных:

```
public class CustomerRegistrationContext : DbContext
{           
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Region> Regions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerRegistrationDbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<CustomerRegistrationContext>
{   
    protected sealed override void Seed(CustomerRegistrationContext dbContext)
    {
        Country russiaCountry = dbContext.Countries.Add(new Country { Name = "Россия" });

        Region moscowRegion = dbContext.Regions.Add(new Region { Name = "Московская область", Country = russiaCountry });
        Region vladimirRegion = dbContext.Regions.Add(new Region { Name = "Владимирская область", Country = russiaCountry });

        City korolevCity = dbContext.Cities.Add(new City { Name = "Королёв", Country = russiaCountry, Region = moscowRegion });
        dbContext.Cities.Add(new City { Name = "Михнево", Country = russiaCountry, Region = moscowRegion });

        City kirzhachCity = dbContext.Cities.Add(new City { Name = "Киржач", Country = russiaCountry, Region = vladimirRegion });
        dbContext.Cities.Add(new City { Name = "Суздаль", Country = russiaCountry, Region = vladimirRegion });

        dbContext.Customers.Add(new Customer { LastName = "Иванов", FirstName = "Иван", City = korolevCity });
        dbContext.Customers.Add(new Customer { LastName = "Петров", FirstName = "Пётр", City = kirzhachCity });

        dbContext.SaveChanges();
        base.Seed(dbContext);
    }
}
```

Возникает вот такая ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если быть точнее, то она возникает именно вот здесь:

```
Country russiaCountry = dbContext.Countries.Add(new Country { Name = "Россия" });
```

В чём моя ошибка? Что я делаю не так в своих классах? С Code-First в первый раз работаю, мало практики, к сожалению.

Есть ещё второй вопрос: есть класс CustomerRegistrationDbInitializer. От какого базового класса в Entity Framework мне наследоваться, чтобы не возникала ошибка, связанная с существованием базы данных? К сожалению, скриншот не смог сделать, как только получится отловить исключение, добавлю скрин к своему вопросу. Суть в чём моего вопроса: мне нужно сделать так, чтобы если у меня в папке App_Data нет локальной базы данных, то её создавать в этой папке и инициализировать определёнными значениями, а если есть база данных, то ничего вообще не делать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> В чём моя ошибка? Что я делаю не так в своих классах? С Code-First в первый раз работаю, мало практики, к сожалению.

Давайте смотреть вашу модель.

1. В таблице `Region` есть внешний ключ на таблицу `Country`
2. В таблице `City` есть два внешних ключа: на таблицу `Country` и на таблицу `Region`.

По-умолчанию, EF генерит связь с каскадным удалением для внешнего ключа. 
Рассмотрим пример, предположим, мы удаляем запись из таблицы `Country`. Запускается цепочка каскадных удалений

1. Удалить запись из таблицы `Region`(внешний ключ в таблице `Region` `CountryId`)
2. Удалить запись из таблицы `City`(внешний ключ в таблице `City` `CountryId`)
3. Снова удалить запись из таблицы `'City'`(внешний ключ в таблице `City` `RegionId`), так как пункт 1 вызывает удаление из таблицы `Region`

Пункт 2 и 3 и вызывают данную ошибку(https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/321843/error-message-1785-occurs-when-you-create-a-foreign-key-constraint-tha)

> Никакая таблица не должна появляться больше
>   одного раза в списке всех каскадных ссылочных действий, вызванных
>   инструкциями DELETE или UPDATE. Кроме того, в дереве каскадных
>   ссылочных действий к любой из задействованных таблиц должен быть
>   только один путь.

Вы должны либо для пункта 2, либо для пункта 3 выставить ограничение NO ACTION. По моему мнению, логично выставить для внешнего ключа в таблице `City` для ключа `CountryId` ограничение NoAction. 
В этом случае, у вас сначала удалиться записи в таблице `Region`, а дальше автоматически удаляться записи из таблицы `City`. 
Тогда создание схемы БД пройдет успешно.

Для этого в методе `OnModelCreating` контекста попробуйте прописать следующее:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     modelBuilder.Entity<Country>().HasMany(t => t.Cities).WithRequired(a=>a.Country).WillCascadeOnDelete(false); 
}
```

> Есть ещё второй вопрос: есть класс CustomerRegistrationDbInitializer.
>   От какого базового класса в Entity Framework мне наследоваться, чтобы
>   не возникала ошибка, связанная с существованием базы данных?

Ваша стратегия инициализатора будет удалять БД всегда, когда у вас изменилась модель. [Здесь](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx) перечислены существующие стратегии инициализации. 
 Я думаю, что вы должны использовать стратегию `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`(от наследоваться от этого класса). Она будет инициализировать БД только тогда, когда базы нет.

Comment: Большое вам спасибо за развёрнутый ответ на мои вопросы. Прошу прощения, что долго не мог отреагировать на ваш ответ. У меня возникли ещё пару вопросов к вам, если вам не трудно, то можете, пожалуйста, ответить на них. 1) После вашего ответа я всё-таки решил использовать `Fluent API` вместо `Data Annotations`: https://ibb.co/hoxBic , Вместо `ModelBuilder` использую `Configuration`. Если я использую `Configuration`, то что мне делать с 21 строчкой на скриншоте? Эту строчку нужно ли выносить в отдельный класс, например, `CountryConfig` или допускается так делать в методе `OnModelCreating`?

Comment: Второй вопрос: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx Хочу на примере Convention 4 по ссылке преобразовать свой класс `Customer` (класс мой приведён выше в моём вопросе). Имеет ли смысл ссылочное свойство на сущность `City` делать обязательным или это будет лишним?

Comment: я бы строчку 21 перенес в конфиг CityConfig, так как мы настраиваем внешний ключ для сущности City к таблице Country.

Comment: @Cuurjol, по той модели, которая имеется, у вас Customer должен всегда ссылаться на существующий город, пользователь без города не может быть, поэтому внешний ключ в таблице Customer должен быть ненулевой, соответственно свойство должно быть обязательным.